# Root password is asked for anything after dist-upgrade

Tags: debian, upgrade, authorization

I'm using Debian Stretch and today I did `apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`. After that, nearly every action is started to ask root password, including external monitor plug/unplug, USB harddisk mount, suspend, etc...

Why is that? How can I trace this issue?

Comment: [Have You Tried Turning It Off And On Again?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)

Answer (score 1):

After running another `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` and after a reboot, everything started to work just fine.